# Java wait() and notify() not working properly

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I'm new in Java Multithreading and I'm stuck in one problem.

```
public class WaitAndNotify {

   private static List<String> strings = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Operator().start();
       new Machine().start();
   }

   // Operator thread
   static class Operator extends Thread {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           while (true) {
               System.out.println("Operator is working");
               synchronized (strings) {
                   strings.add(scanner.nextLine());
                   strings.notify();
                   System.out.println("Notifying to machine");
               }
               try {
                   sleep(1000);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }
   }

   // Machine thread
   static class Machine extends Thread {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           while (strings.isEmpty()) {
               synchronized (strings) {
                   try {
                       strings.wait();
                       System.out.println("Machine is waiting");
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   System.out.println(strings.remove(0));
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I have operator and machine `threads`. I start each thread and when I write something in console, it has to `notify` machine and machine has to print it. That's working, but sometimes machine not calls. When I remove the `thread.sleep()` part after `notify`, it's not working at all.

The console when everything works fine.

```
Operator is working
Hi...               // That's our message that we write in console
Notifying to machine
Machine is waiting
Hi...              // Machine printed our message successfully after 1 second
Operator is working
```

What happens if the `thread.sleep()` part is removed.

```
Operator is working
Hi...             // That's our message that we write in console
Notifying to machine
Operator is working
```

As you see machine is not working. I don't know maybe it locked or something else. So can anyone explain to me why the machine not prints our message when `thread.sleep()` is removed?

Comment: The Operator is just waiting for input.

Comment: There really are better, more high level methods to achieve synchronization. I'd suggest using a `BlockingQueue` which would give you the behavior you want for free essentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove sleep, machine has to wait until lock is released which is after

```
System.out.println("Notifying to machine");
```

After that line, both machine and operator race for the lock. If operator beats machine to it, then it will ask for input 2nd time before machine prints anything. After this point, machine will only be able to print one time and then exit the while loop. Because it removes only 1 element from array so array will always have more than 0 elements.

Following version works fine

```
    static class Operator extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Operator is working");
            synchronized (strings) {
                System.out.println("Notifying to machine1");
                strings.add(scanner.nextLine());
                strings.notify();
                System.out.println("Notifying to machine2");
                try {
                    strings.wait();
                }catch (Exception ex){}
            }
        }
    }
}

// Machine thread
static class Machine extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (strings.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("strings is empty");
            synchronized (strings) {
                strings.notify();
                try {
                    System.out.println("Machine is waiting 1");
                    strings.wait();
                    System.out.println("Machine is waiting 2");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(strings.remove(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if there is no sleep, operator is able to acquire the lock multiple times without giving machine a chance. If this happens, array will have at least 2 elements. If machine acquires the lock, it will print once and then return since `while(strings.isEmpty())` will return false

Comment: Ok thank you. I understood a little, but not completely))